# Как использовать метод из модели в to_json only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Создал в модели метод `nice_title`:

```
def nice_title
    title.titleize
end
```

Как мне его теперь использовать в `to_json(only: ...)`?

Просто `title` работает, но вот `nice_title` попросту игнорируется.

Comment: Так может, [`:methods` надо, а не `:only`?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: @D-side извиняюсь что так долго не отвечал. Сейчас снова добрался до этого участка. `:methods` тоже не помог. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @D-side Вру :) Изменилось. `:methods` надо использовать отдельно от `:only`. `:only` отвечает за дефолтные поля таблицы.

Comment: Всё-таки завелось? Оставьте ответ тогда.